# Restriction in bayesian likelihood expression

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, constraint, restrictions

I'm doing MCMC simulation but I'm confused in some part of my model. I dont know which of my likelihood expression is right.

My model is as following.

$\gamma$ = $(\gamma_{1},\cdots,\gamma_{K})$ and $\gamma_{K}$ is depend on $\gamma_{1:(K-1)}$, which is 
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{K} = 
\left\{
        \begin{array}{lr}
             0, & \sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k} = 0 \\
             1, & \sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k} = 1.\\
             bernoulli(\theta_{K}), &\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k} >1  
             \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}.
Ang for $k = 1, \cdots, K-1 $. $\gamma_{k} \sim bernoulli(\theta_{k})$.

Now I have prior on $\theta_{1:K}$, which denotes by $p(\theta_{1},\cdots,\theta_{K})$.

So my likelihood should be

$likili = p(\gamma \mid \theta)*p(\theta)$

But I'm confused that which of the following form is right?

(1) $likeli = \big[\delta_{0}(\gamma_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}=0}]} 
 \delta_{1}(\gamma_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}=1}]} ber(\theta_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}>1}]} \prod_{k=1}^{K-1}ber(\theta_{k}) \big]* \prod_{k=1}^{K}p(\theta_{k}) $

(2) $likeli = \big[\delta_{0}(\gamma_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}=1}]}
 \delta_{1}(\gamma_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}=1}]} ber(\theta_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}>1}]} \prod_{k=1}^{K-1}ber(\theta_{k}) \big]* \big[ \prod_{k=1}^{K-1}p(\theta_{k}) \big] * p(\theta_{K})^{\mathbf{1}[{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}>1}]} $

The difference in two likelihood is that whether prior on $\theta_{K}$ should be add directly, or should be add after considering $\gamma_{1:(K-1)}?$

Comment: The model is incomplete as it does not cover the case $\sum_k\gamma_k<1$. And the prior $p(\theta)$ appears in the posterior [not the likelihood] no matter what the data is. The prior cannot depend on the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Xi'an I think it's complete, since $\gamma_{K}$ is depend on the $\gamma_{1:(K-1)}$. There are only three case for $\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\gamma_{k}$, which in $>1$ , $ = 1$ and $ =0$.  Besides, since prior should appears in the posterior no matter what the data is, that mean form (1) is right?